# What are the constraints for the Azure Sql Server administrator login name?

Tags: azure-sql-server

I am creating it using the following terraform code:

```
resource "azurerm_sql_server" "instance" {
    name                         = "${local.resource_group_name}-sql-${random_integer.sql_num.result}"
    resource_group_name          = local.resource_group_name
    location                     = local.location
    version                      = "12.0"
    administrator_login          = "admin"
    administrator_login_password = random_password.sql_password.result

    tags = {
        environment = var.env
    }
}
```

Yet I get this:

```
Error: Error waiting on create/update future for SQL Server "app505-dfpg-qa-data-eastus2-sql-53398" (Resource Group "app505-dfpg-qa-data-eastus2"): Code="InvalidLoginName" Message="'admin' is not a valid login name in this version of SQL Server."
```

OK, so what is a valid login name? Google seems to be suspiciously silent on the subject.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The name "admin" is not a valid login name, the correct admin login name of the Azure SQL Server should be:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is stupid. Not your answer. The issue causing it. Since the dawn of man, when T-rex was roaming the streets, it's always been *sa*. So says the Bible and the holy Q'ran. Why, oh why, do they horse around with that?! And before someone yells *security!* - set a proper password and protect it. No need to change *sa* to something locally decided. It **will** be forgotten, distorted, confused and the dude who came up with it will either get amnesia or hit by a bus. Also, that name will need to be stored somewhere and it will be on a piece of paper under a keyboard. Security my sitting device!

Comment: Also: +1 for a good and helpful answer.